# Deep Neural Network : Probability issue

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow, probability, deep-learning

I'm working on a keyword spotting with deep neural network (Multi-Layer Perceptron) and I'm facing a following issue.

I have to detect a keyword in a speech signal. I use the library Tensorflow and I write my code based on this [example](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/multilayer_perceptron.py).

```
'''
A Multilayer Perceptron implementation example using TensorFlow library.
This example is using the MNIST database of handwritten digits
(http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/)
Author: Aymeric Damien
Project: https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/
'''

# Import MINST data
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("/tmp/data/", one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf

# Parameters
learning_rate = 0.001
training_epochs = 15
batch_size = 100
display_step = 1

# Network Parameters
n_hidden_1 = 256 # 1st layer number of features
n_hidden_2 = 256 # 2nd layer number of features
n_input = 784 # MNIST data input (img shape: 28*28)
n_classes = 10 # MNIST total classes (0-9 digits)

# tf Graph input
x = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_input])
y = tf.placeholder("float", [None, n_classes])


# Create model
def multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases):
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights['h1']), biases['b1'])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)
    # Hidden layer with RELU activation
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights['h2']), biases['b2'])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)
    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.matmul(layer_2, weights['out']) + biases['out']
    return out_layer

# Store layers weight & bias
weights = {
    'h1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_input, n_hidden_1])),
    'h2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1, n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2, n_classes]))
}
biases = {
    'b1': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_1])),
    'b2': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden_2])),
    'out': tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes]))
}

# Construct model
pred = multilayer_perceptron(x, weights, biases)

# Define loss and optimizer
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(pred, y))
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

# Initializing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# Launch the graph
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)

    # Training cycle
    for epoch in range(training_epochs):
        avg_cost = 0.
        total_batch = int(mnist.train.num_examples/batch_size)
        # Loop over all batches
        for i in range(total_batch):
            batch_x, batch_y = mnist.train.next_batch(batch_size)
            # Run optimization op (backprop) and cost op (to get loss value)
            _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                          y: batch_y})
            # Compute average loss
            avg_cost += c / total_batch
        # Display logs per epoch step
        if epoch % display_step == 0:
            print "Epoch:", '%04d' % (epoch+1), "cost=", \
                "{:.9f}".format(avg_cost)
    print "Optimization Finished!"

    # Test model
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
    # Calculate accuracy
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, "float"))
    print "Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: mnist.test.images, y: mnist.test.labels})
```

I trained my network using MFCC features with double delta. In inputs, I have 2300 inputs which correspond to the MFCC for around 600ms in order to add context. In outputs, I have 2 classes, `mykeyword` and an other class `filler`.

I have a 3x128 MLP with ReLU activations and softmax output layer. I have also centered and whitened my data.

My labels vector looks like : `[ 1 0 ]` for the keyword and `[ 0 1 ]` for the "filler".

I would like to get a probability at the end which traduces the confidence score of detecting the keyword, thus I can use a threshold. However , after the softmax layer, I get only `0` or `1` for each examples of the testing data. I don't really understand why..

Thank you

Comment: Try to print the values of `pred`. If they are very high / low (like `1000` or `-1000` you might have an issue with the optimization, and that would explain that you get only `0` and `1`

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've print the pred values and I noticed that I have high and low value such as `[ 14225.61132812   5236.04931641]`. I don't understand why I have this kind of values because when I'm printing the weights and the biases, their values are very low (around 10^-2).

Comment: Is your input normalized? It should ideally have values in `[-1., 1.]`, although I don't know much about speech recognition. You can also try to lower your learning rate and see what happens.

Comment: Yes, my inputs are whitened and centered in order to have a mean of 0 and a std of 1. My input looks like this for one example : `[ -4.99293470e+00  -1.87000704e+00   1.94133902e+00 ...,  -1.36777281e-03
   3.67879146e-03  -8.94929166e-04]`. Currently, my learning rate is 0.001, I will try to lower it.

Comment: Also when initializing the weights with [`tf.random_normal`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#random_normal), make sure to put the argument `stddev` to something around `0.01`

Comment: I tried both configurations, with stddev = `0.01`and also with a lower learning rate. With stddev = `0.01`, I have something better in output such as : `[ 44.7891922   31.90212822]`. However the probability still stucks between 0 and 1 : `[  9.99997497e-01   2.53056874e-06]`. When I lower the learning rate, I got an output value of `[ 0 0 ]`.

Comment: You need to reduce more the sttdev, until you reach `pred` around `[-3, 3]`

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I found that the issue can be the weights initialization as you said (http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap3.html#weight_initialization). I will try different configuration of weights initialization and tell you if there is any progress.

Comment: Finally, I used the glorot uniform which solves this issue. I will try to learn my network with more data. Thanks you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the world where numbers are infinitely precise, your model would be slightly different. You would actually use `tf.nn.softmax` at the end of your model, and optimize for `cross_entropy`. However, numbers have precision, and computing gradients for cross entropy followed by a softmax during the backward pass will result in numerical instability.

The thing is, the combined gradient of `softmax -> cross_entropy` is very stable (it is just the output of softmax for correct predictions and `output - 1` for incorrect). Therefore, tensorflow allows you to optimize directly for `softmax + crossentropy`, in which case it uses that stable way of computing the gradient.

That introduces a problem -- no node in your graph actually computes the probability, the probabilities are hidden inside that objective function.

To address it, add an extra node to your graph:

```
prob = tf.nn.softmax(pred)
```

And evaluate it. It will return you the actual probabilities.

The `0` and `1` you observe are likely to be the outputs of `argmax`. `argmax` is "hard" in a sense that it just returns the largest value, not the probabilities (and the largest value conveniently matches whether you compute it before the softmax or after).

Comment: Actually, I have had an this line on my code, and the `[0 1]` already represents the probability.

Comment: Do you have it locally? I don't see it in the snippet in the question

Comment: Yes I have it, the snippet shown is not my code, but I used this code to make mine.